# i don't know wher is error my aplication force close

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

this is a ERROR :

com.example.myapplication.activity_add.onCreate(activity_add.kt:29)

this is Mycode:

```
package com.example.myapplication

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.Toast
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase

class activity_add() : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var Etbarang: EditText
    private lateinit var Etkegiatan: EditText
    private lateinit var Etbagian: EditText
    private lateinit var Btnsimpan: Button
    private lateinit var dbref : DatabaseReference
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add)

        Etbagian = findViewById(R.id.Etbagian)
        Etkegiatan = findViewById(R.id.Etkegiatan)
        Etbarang = findViewById(R.id.Etbarang)

        dbref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("aktivitas")

        Btnsimpan.setOnClickListener{
            savedata()
        }
    }

    private fun savedata() {
        val bagian = Etbagian.text.toString()
        val keterangan = Etkegiatan.text.toString()
        val barang = Etbarang.text.toString()

        if (barang.isEmpty()){
            Etbarang.error = "masukan nama barang"
            return
        }
        if (bagian.isEmpty()){
            Etbagian.error = "masukan nama bagian"
            return
        }
        if (keterangan.isEmpty()){
            Etkegiatan.error = "Masukan kegiatan"
            return
        }
        val empid = dbref.push().key!!
        val add = add_kegiatan(empid,bagian,barang,keterangan)

        dbref.child(empid).setValue(add).addOnCompleteListener{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Data Berhasil di tambahkan", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }.addOnFailureListener{ err->
            Toast.makeText(this,"error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}
```

i try to make add form for firebase that my coding when i run it the application closed automatically and i got this error at logcat

> Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property Btnsimpan has not been initialized
> >at com.example.myapplication.activity_add.onCreate(activity_add.kt:29)

my application get close when i open the activity contain this code an the error say it at line 30

Comment: Your error states that "property Btnsimpan has not been initialized". This is because you haven't initialized the button in the OnCreate. You need to initialize it..

Answer (score 1):

you defined the property `Btnsimpan` as `lateinint` and you are trying to use it with the on-click listener but you haven't initiated it yet.
just do something like this before the click event

```
Btnsimpan = findViewById(R.id.Btnsimpan)
```

of course you need to create a view with this id first